# When I mount an XFS snapshot that was frozen, do I need to unfreeze it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, xfs

I'm snapshotting an XFS EBS volume, freezing it first.

When I mount the snapshot as a new volume on a different instance will I need to unfreeze the volume before it can be used, or will it not be frozen after mounting it?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary to unfreeze the XFS file system, even though it was frozen when you performed the EBS snapshot.

You can restore the EBS snapshot into an EBS volume, attach the volume to an instance, mount the XFS file system, and use the file system immediately without any unfreeze operation.